# Переадресация домена в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Я пытаюсь перенаправить некоторые домены на другой айпи у себя на ubuntu через файл /etc/hosts. Я столкнулся с проблемой: при подмене домена youtube.com на другой айпи, браузер не переходит на новый айпи. Вот сам файл hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       youtube.com
127.0.0.1       vk.com
```

Я перезагружал сервис networking, но при переходе на youtube.com у меня открывается настоящий айпи сайта вместо 127.0.0.1. Пользуюсь браузером Chrome. Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему.

Comment: Возможно браузер настроен на использование внешнего DNS-сервера

Comment: А здесь есть какой-то выход?

Comment: Смотря зачем ты это делаешь и что ещё есть в твоей локалке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно просто кэш браузера, можно зачистить его,в новых вкладках:

```
chrome://net-internals/#dns
```

и сокеты:

```
chrome://net-internals/#sockets
```

какая версия убунты? в последних версиях используется свой dns который временно кэширует записи. для сброса кэша нужно выполнить:

```
systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```